# Can you help me understand what is being said?

Tags: pronunciation, listening

I like to challenge my listening skills seeing videos/listening to podcasts or similar contents and try to understand what is being said, but I usually can't understand what people say even if playing the videos at the mininum speed. In this case what the automatic transcription shows doesn't make sense to me and I hope someone can help me with this.

It's between 2:06 and 2:09

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dkhw79KLPHc

I believe that I hear the words "runs" and "sick" but couldn't guess the rest.

Is It unclear even for a native speaker?

Thanks!

Comment: Link to the video doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I see. It must be some kind of geoblocking because the link works for me.

Answer (score 1):

> "Your runs were sick"

A "run" is a technical term in singing: a series of notes sung over a single syllable. And "sick" is slang for "very good"

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea of what she says after "It was so" and before "your runs were sick"? The automatic transcription shows "It was so lex Kennedy" but I don't think that that is what she says. It's about 2:06